# sql (query) checking for duplicate record on duplicate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

ok this is my data in the table

```
field1  field2   field 3                    field4
107     0        2011-01-01 00:00:00.000    2613
107     0        2011-01-01 00:00:00.000    2613
```

how can i check for all the duplicate records in the table with this dataset in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4, count(*)
from mytable
group by 1,2,3,4
having count(*) > 1;
```